# CSS overflow hidden with floating divs and without width

Tags: html, css

I want to reach a one line layout with divs, where one div should be shortened with overflow:hidden. All elements are floated. I want that parts of the .title are shortened when it reaches the float-right div. Is there any solution without setting a width or using javascript?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="float-left icon"><span class=" icon ">Z</span>
</div>
<div class="float-left title ">
<p>Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text.</p>
</div>
<div class="float-right ">
<div class="right ">
    <a><span class="icon ">ICON</span></a>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
    .container {
    width: 100%;
}
    .float-left {
        float: left;
    }
    .title p {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    .float-right {
        float:right;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eok46kba/62/

Comment: I would suggest studying some of the popular frameworks with grid support like bootstrap.
Altough it is certainly possible to solve your issue with adding some css attributes, it is questionable if it is really that bullet-proof like bootstrap's approach when it comes to browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Use % width:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.icon {
    background:yellow;
}
.float-left {
    float: left;
    width:15%;
}
.title {
    width:70%;   
    background:red;
}
.title p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.float-right {
    float:right;
}
```

Edit: (posted wrong jsfiddle) https://jsfiddle.net/eok46kba/64/

But your style nowrap makes your title a one-liner.

Comment: I know it works with %, but I cannot determine the %.

Comment: Why cant you determine the % ?
If you cant determine %, maybe you can use static values and fix your page with http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Because I add and remove Content from this div.

Comment: Well without javascript I dont know think this is possible, sorry. If you find anything please let me know.